# RxJava2 flatMap operator

Tags: android, rx-java2

I'm try to use the flatMap operator to make two request using retrofit on Android. The idea is make the first request to get the users and after that make the second request which I need to know the total of users that I get to make the second request. This is the way I'm trying to do it.

```
remoteDataSource.requestAuthors()
            .flatMap {remoteDataSource.requestAvatars(it.size) }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe { 
                //here I need the authors and avatars to create the new object
            }
```

Is the flatMap the correct operator to do that? Thanks!

Answer - Yes!

**Updating**

In that case, should I do something like that?

```
override fun requestAuthors(): Observable<List<AuthorResponse>> {
        val authors = mutableListOf<Author>()
        val authorResponse = remoteDataSource.requestAuthors()
            .doOnNext { authors.addAll(it) }
            .flatMap { remoteDataSource.requestAvatars(it.size) }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .doOnNext {avatars->
                avatars.results.forEach { avatar ->
                    authors.forEach { author ->
                        author.avatarUrl = avatar
                    }
                }
            }

        return authorResponse

    }
```

Comment: *Is the flatMap the correct operator to do that* yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, `flatMap` is a great operator to do stuff like this. You will handle errors from each request and they will execute one after another. 

If you need to do something between these two requests, use `doOnSuccess()` operator.

```
remoteDataSource.requestAuthors()
                .doOnSuccess { /*interact with authors*/ }
                .flatMap {remoteDataSource.requestAvatars(it.size) }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe {
            /*interact with avatart*/
        }
```

Comment: I think, you will assign the last avatar in list to all authors in your code.

Comment: Acutally not, I need assign each avatar for each author.

Comment: Then you need one foreach loop for both collections. And obviously they both should have the same number of elements.

Comment: authors.forEachIndexed { index, author ->
        author.avatarUrl = avatarsList[index]
    }